# Indutor and capacitor selection for DC-DC convertor

Tags: dc-dc-converter

Assummed that I got some value from calculation to meet required Voltage ripple and current comsumption at specific switching frequency (says 100kHz).

**For capacitor.**

As real capacitor don't behave like ideal one. How to select multiple capacitor type, value to paralel to meet requirement above. Also we can't make Ideal frequency response. which reponse is okay in this application? How we can pick real capacitor to make the circuit?

**For Inductor.**
Based on maximum inductor current how to select copper wire size? (take skin effect into account)

**For Example**
I used [adafruit boost calculator](https://learn.adafruit.com/diy-boost-calc/the-calculator) with requirement below.
[image]

And I got this component value.
[image]

How I pick real component from this value?
Also for inductor I might made by my self. How to select copper wire size?

Answer (score 1):

Below is the buck regulator datasheet from Texas instruments, In this datasheet he has given the detailed explanation to calculate the inductor and capacitor value.

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slus973a/slus973a.pdf?ts=1599540205561&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Refer the page number: 20

or

https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva477b/slva477b.pdf?ts=1601357038612&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

I hope it helps